# no module named "3rd party library" in subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x

My folder structure is as follows.

- main

  - main.py
  - library

    - utils.py

utils.py has the following code

```
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
def testAuth():
  print('some code code')
```

main.py has the following code

```
from library.utils import testAuth
def start():
   print ('some code')
```

I have run `pip install aws_requests_auth` in both my main and library folder.

When i tried to run `python3 main.py` I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from library.utils import testAuth
  File "/Users/Docs/library/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aws_requests_auth'
```

How do i ensure 3rd party libraries are installed properly for sub folders? Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems to be confused. Whether the code which tries to `import` something is in a subdirectory or not is inconsequential. *Probably* the environment where you are running your Python code is different from the environment where you ran `pip`. Make sure they both have the same `PYTHONPATH` etc.

Comment: Using `python3 -m pip install some_package` rather than `pip install some_package` avoids this problem altogether.

Comment: Thank you! that worked. I wonder why though.